# JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 - Showing Popup on Page Load

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I am trying to show a popup when a page loads. I have a generic popup embedded in each page that should be shown if there are data in the popup itself. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
  $(function() { // initial page load
    $(document).on("pagechange",  
      function(event) {
        var pageId = $(document).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" )[0].id;
        displayMessages(pageId);
      });
    });
  }
```

I've looked at every other sample I've seen on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to work. The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; 
attempted to call method "open".
```

So, when can I call popup("open") on a popup?

**EDIT TO INCLUDE displayMessage FUNCTION**

```
function displayMessages(pageId) {
  pageId = pageId || $("body").pagecontainer( "getActivePage" )[0].id;
  try { 
    var errCount = parseInt( $(jq(pageId + ".errorCount")).val() );
    if ( !isNaN(errCount) && errCount ) 
    {
      $( jq(pageId + ".errors") ).popup( "open" );
    }
    else if ( $(jq(pageId + ".message")).text() != "" )
    {
      $( jq(pageId + ".message") ).popup( "open" );
    }
  } catch (e) { 
    alert(e); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Post displayMessage function.

Comment: Remove `$(function()` you don't need it. Replace `pagechange` with `pagecontainershow`. Wrap `.popup("open")` in `setTimeout(function(){ open popup }, 50);`. Make sure that popup's direct parent is page div. `$(document).pagecontainer` should be `$('body').pagecontainer`.